# Showing $f_n(x) = nx$ is not equicontinuous in any point of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that $$f_n(x) = nx$$

is not equicontinuous in any point of $\mathbb{R}$. By the definition, a sequence of functions is equicontinuous if for every $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ such that

$$|x-y|<\delta \implies |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$$

that is, all functions are continuous in $y$ and this $\delta$ is the same for all.

Let's analyze:

$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| = |n(x-y)|$$

I thought of saying that:

$$|n(x-y)|>\delta$$

then by choosing $\delta = \epsilon$ we'd have this thing being $>\epsilon$ when it should be smaller, whenever $|x-y|<\delta$

Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right because one could choose a smaller $\delta$.

Comment: I don't really understand your argument, but you could say that $f_n$ is equicontinuous, so there would one $δ$ doing the job for one random $ε$. But since $n|(x-y)|$ is unbounded then there would always be a $n_0$ surpassing $ε$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by your argumentation $f_n$ wouldn't even be a continuous function. You can't simply choose a $\delta$ and say that the condition is not satisfied - you need to show that there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ so that the condition is not fulfilled for *any* $\delta > 0$.

Assume there is a $\delta > 0$ that satisfies $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < 1$. Now choose $x = 0$, $y = \frac{2}{\delta}$ and $n > \frac{2}{\delta}$. Then $|x - y| = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$, but $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| = n \frac{\delta}{2} > 1$, which is a contradiction.